# Different Validator For Create and Update in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, validation, crud

I looking for different validation style for forms when I create and update entities.

For Instance, when I create an "UserClass" object it requires an ID to define, but when I update, I do not need ID again, because it is defined by user at the creation step. I have lots of entity and I need to find most proper way.

For instance is this logical?

```
public interface RecordGroupValidator {

    public void validateNew(RecordGroup recordGroup, Errors errors);

    public void validateUpdate(RecordGroup recordGroup, Errors errors);
}
```

Validator :

```
public class RecordGroupValidatorImpl implements RecordGroupValidator {

    @Autowired
    RecordGroupService recordGroupService;

    @Override
    public void validateNew(RecordGroup recordGroup, Errors errors) {
        if (!ValidationHandler.validText(recordGroup.getIds())) {
            errors.rejectValue(ColumnIdentifier.COLUMN.Ids.name(), TextParameters.SERVLET_RESPONSE.InvalidParameter.getText());
        }
        if (!ValidationHandler.validText(recordGroup.getName())) {
            errors.rejectValue(ColumnIdentifier.COLUMN.Name.name(), TextParameters.SERVLET_RESPONSE.InvalidParameter.getText());
        }
        if (recordGroup.getRecordGroupType() == null) {
            errors.rejectValue(ColumnIdentifier.COLUMN.RecordGroupType.name(), TextParameters.SERVLET_RESPONSE.InvalidParameter.getText());
        }
        if (recordGroupService.idsExist(recordGroup.getIds())) {
            errors.rejectValue(ColumnIdentifier.COLUMN.Ids.name(), TextParameters.SERVLET_RESPONSE.DuplicateEntry.getText());
        }
        if (recordGroupService.nameExist(recordGroup.getName())) {
            errors.rejectValue(ColumnIdentifier.COLUMN.Name.name(), TextParameters.SERVLET_RESPONSE.DuplicateEntry.getText());
        }
}

    @Override
    public void validateUpdate(RecordGroup recordGroup, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, ColumnIdentifier.COLUMN.Name.name(), TextParameters.SERVLET_RESPONSE.InvalidParameter.getText());
        if (recordGroup.getRecordGroupType() == null) {
            errors.rejectValue(ColumnIdentifier.COLUMN.Type.name(), TextParameters.SERVLET_RESPONSE.InvalidParameter.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create two validation. One for create and one for update. This will create clever architecture. Because for now you have only one difference but in the future you can have more. In my opinion you should split them now.

Comment: How about above example? For one entity, I defined "validateNew" method for create operation and I defined "validateUpdate" method for update operation. This works but it is hard to apply same method for tens of entity.

Comment: For me it's better to write more code but when you want to add new feature to be able to add it easy. But you can write some common logic and call it in the two methods. Or you can try to write some dynamic code with reflection.

Comment: Me too, I prefer to write more and clear code. But in the professional world, developers can say that you write to much code. While I developing codes I try to do it more professional and I can not be sure what I do.

Comment: They can say what they want. If they don't understand the good practices it's their problem.

Comment: i had the same question but i think we can say this is worth discussion and depending on case, especially the schema and importance of the object you're working with.